# Hosting java web application with oracle database

Tags: oracle11g, hosting, web-hosting, java-ee-5

I have been trying to find out how best I can host a `JavaEE5` web application with `Oracle11g` database. I have got my domain registered and currently pointing to my `Jboss` web application on my laptop.

I would like to host it for a while untill my application gets finished and ideally would like to go on hosting on a professional company server when I start getting increased traffic.

Firstly, to host at my home I want to use a separate dedicated server. Can you please let me know what options I have? Because I have no clue on what to purchase.

Secondly, when I want to go with a professional company server, which ones should I consider that supports `JavaEE5` deployments and `Oracle11g` databases? Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: How much are you planning to pay per month for hosting?

Comment: And is it principle for your application to use Oracle DB and JEE application server. Are you developing personal application with preference to host it at free hosting, or it's business application where response time is critical and where free hosting is too slow?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Well, I have no clue to be honest how much I'm going to pay, I would rather ask how much they want and what they provide. How much I pay depends on how good my site is doing. But, to start with I can pay £5pm. Well, I can change my database to something like MySql if need be. I would like to first test my application hosting at my home. I'll be happy to see any options on that as well. My site is going to be a technical information providing free of cost as I want it to use some part for charity.

Comment: hi @ IndoKnight i have same query planning to host java app with oracle 11g any suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I have experience with [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/). Free plan offers JBoss AS 7.1.1 and MySQL or PostgreSQL, but it's very slow (you might want to try these two my demo applications: [personal site](http://dsps-sukharevd.rhcloud.com/) and [e-shop](http://shopzilla-sukharevd.rhcloud.com)). Paid plans looks for me too expensive here. This solution might be appropriate if you don't wanna configure application server and database.

Another possible solution is [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com). There are such services as [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) that offers you different servers including Tomcat, [Amazon Relational Database Service](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) that offers you Oracle Database as well as other RDMSes, and [Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) that enable you install JBoss AS yourself even if Beanstalk with Tomcat doesn't work for you. It looks like AWS is cheaper than OpenShift, but as for me, EC2 is still expensive. Check if price works for you. Buy the way AWS has a free tier the first year of usage that includes EC2 instance. So if you're sure that your project will long less than a year, it might be a good choice. ASW would be appropriate for you if you are ok with Tomcat instead of application server and you don't wanna configure application server and database.

Also I heard positive comments about [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/), but never tried it. It looks like it offers only infrastructure as service (like AWS EC2) so you will have to install and configure all servers yourself.

Comment: Thanks very much for your elaborate reply. I'll take a look and get back to you, cheers.

Comment: Can we use Openshift for a domain name and change it later on to another hosting provider without much of a hassle?

Comment: Well, I've never migrated application from openshift, but I don't see what can cause problems if you use custom domain name (not rhcloud.com). Although DNS changes usually applies during 48 hours, that could be pain in the ass for any hosting, because during 48h you would have to maintain both applications. But again, it would be problem with DNS, not with hosting. You don't change your application for OpenShift and you Red Hat don't impose restrictions, so I don't see any possible problems with migration.